# What does the "aggregate list" do for LINQ group by clauses?

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531412.aspx) page implies that I can do something like this:

```
From thing In things
Group By thing.ID Into result = Group, Sum(thing.value)
```

And then be able to use the `Sum` of values later on. Perhaps in something like this (not actually working code):

```
From thing In things
Group By thing.name Into results = Group, Sum(thing.value)
Where results.Sum >= 10
From result In results
Select result
```

This should select all `thing`s where the sum of values for `thing`s with the same name is greater than 10.

Through more testing, I can't get `results` to be anything other than the first item in a so called aggregate list. In other words the following are effectively identical as far as I can tell:

```
Group By thing.name Into results = Group, Sum(thing.value)

Group By thing.name Into results = Group
```

What is this aggregate list even supposed to do and how can I use it?

A side note: The example in the link seems to use `Count` instead `Sum` but actually uses two different definitions of `Count` and is worthless as an example.

Comment: In your second code block, try `Where Sum >= 10`.  After the `Group By` I think you have an enumerable of anonymous types with properties `name`, `results` and `Sum`.  `results` is the list of matching `thing`s.  You can also name the `Sum` differently with, e.g. `total = Sum(thing.Value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to understand what exactly is happening when you perform a linq query.

When you do a group by in the query syntax, you're creating result objects with property names of the key and aggregates.

Your query:

```vb
From thing In things
Group By thing.ID Into result = Group, Sum(thing.value)
```

Yields a collection of objects with properties:

> `ID` - the key (implicitly taken from the `ID` property)
>   `result` - a collection of items that is in the group (explicit alias to `Group`)
>   `Sum` - the sum of adding the `value` of the items (implicitly taken from the aggregate name)

Once you understand that, you can do more filtering.  To filter results where the sum is less than 10:

```vb
From thing In things
Group By thing.ID Into result = Group, Sum(thing.value)
Where Sum < 10
```

So to fix your other query, you would do this:

```vb
From thing In things
Group By thing.name Into results = Group, Sum(thing.value)
Where Sum >= 10
From result In results
Select result
```

Comment: Okay so this works, But what if I wanted the sum of many columns, how could I refer to them?

Comment: You'll have to assign an alias to each of the sums. `result = Group` is taking the `Group` of items and assigning it to the `result` property. So you would need something like: `sum1 = Sum(thing.value1), sum2 = Sum(thing.value2), sum3 = Sum(thing.value3)`. In vb.net, the name is implicitly taken from the aggregate method used. C# on the other hand you must explicitly name it.